# Why does GDB think my Fortran string is ~4GiB

Tags: string, fortran, gdb, gfortran, subroutine

I have a Fortran program where I'm trying to pass a string to a subroutine. The code in my example below runs as expected with no error by itself. However, after compiling with:
f95 -g test.f95

and when using GDB to trace through the code things go wrong.

```
program test

  character(len=4):: my_string="asdf"

  call test_routine(my_string)

  contains

  subroutine test_routine(asdf)
    character(len=*) :: asdf
    print*, len(asdf)

    print*, asdf

    return

  end subroutine test_routine

end program test
```

When setting a breakpoint on line 12 between the two print*, statements I get the following output when running the code in GDB

```
Starting program: /home/user/folder/a.out 
           4


Breakpoint 1, test_routine (asdf=<error reading variable: value requires 4158328176 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, _asdf=4) at test.f95:13
13      print*, asdf
```

As is seen in the output, Fortran prints the len() for the string as '4' but GDB sees it as being ~4GiB

What is causing this?

GDB version:
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git

Fortran (gcc) version:
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

Comment: Is GDB supposed to understand fixed-length and assumed-length strings?

Comment: Ok, I see now. Fixed length yes, but assumed length no because only Fortran77 is officially supported by gdb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for assumed-length strings has recently been added to GDB in this commit: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=216a7e6b9e5d2b279276f3bd8c11145a7d9b59ac .

This commit should be part of the upcoming GDB 9 release.  If you want an early preview then you might consider building GDB from source, instructions are here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ .

The documentation stating that only F77 is supported is a little out of date, support for F90 is improving, but is by no means complete.  Bug reports are always welcome as this can help guide which features should be worked on next.

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely something I'd be interested in trying.